# javascript submit default value for unchecked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

In my form, I have a series of checkboxes for the user to agree to certain things. I don't need them to check them all or any specific ones, but I DO need the recipient of the email to easily tell which ones were not checked (terms they didn't agree with)

I have tried adding a hidden checkbox with the same name, but when the visible checkbox is checked, the email gets both responses, resulting in a confusing email.

Radio buttons aren't the answer because I just want the user to see a checkbox and check it (or not!)

fyi, php is not an available option. I would prefer javascript or jquery.

I'm not good with javascript but I tried the following and it didn't work (it sent both responses when the visible one was checked):

```
<input type="hidden" name="Name1" id="Hidden1" value="NOT ANSWERED" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="Name1" id="Visible1" value="Yes" onchange="document.getElementById('Hidden1').checked = false;" />
```

Comment: Somewhere you have to be sending this email from a server, and that's where you should handle this, not on the clientside by adding lots of unneccessary stuff because your serverside code can't handle something as simple as a few checkboxes.

Comment: You're right, it SHOULD be done server-side but I didn't want to do that - they have one script that processes all of their forms so I didn't want to touch it. I ended up writing a script to go between the form and their script and was able to make it work - but it's ugly.  I really thought there might be an easier and more elegant way to do this with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how you can get a default value for an unchecked input using `data` attributes.

HTML

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms_1" data-unchecked-value="not-agree" value="agree" checked />
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms_2" data-unchecked-value="not-agree" value="agree" />
  <button type="submit">
    submit
  </button>
</form>
```

JS

```
var form = document.querySelector('#form')

function getValue(node) {
  return node.checked ? node.value : node.dataset.uncheckedValue
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var terms1 = getValue(this.terms_1)
  var terms2 = getValue(this.terms_2)

  console.log(terms1, terms2)
})
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo6g7so5/1/**

Comment: thank you - I see this working in the console but how do I get it to submit to my form script?  (I admitted up front I'm not good with javascript -sorry!)